# Null pointer constant conversion to a prvalue

Tags: c++, null

Null pointer constant conversion decribed by the following rule sec. 4.10/1 N3797:

> A null pointer constant of integral type can be converted to a prvalue
>   of type std::nullptr_t . [Note: The resulting prvalue is not a null
>   pointer value. —end note]

I thought the following is an example of such conversion:

```
static_cast<std::nullptr_t>(0);
```

But it seems it is no true, because

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    void *p = static_cast<std::nullptr_t>(0);
    cout << p; //0- Why? It is not a null pointer value
}
```

[demo](http://ideone.com/0kBZTk)

Comment: I'm confused (genuinely) - what happens when you send a pointer to std::cout?

Comment: @doctorlove, The address that the pointer contains is printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `p` *is* a null pointer. A prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t` can be converted to any pointer. It is the initializing  expression `static_cast<std::nullptr_t>(0)` which is not a null pointer value.

Comment: That is, value of the prvalue is not a null-pointer-value, but can be converted to him. Could you possibly explain what is the value of `static_cast<std::nullptr_t>(0)`? I think it is `nullptr`.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: It is equal to `nullptr`. It is a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`, and it is the unique such value.